# hibernate query latest record returns null

Tags: java, hibernate

i am trying to return the latest record in a table based on the date it was uploaded - when run the query returns null.

my config is fine as i tested it with asc order and it worked fine + my other queries inside the class work too.

can anyone tell me why this doesnt work, thanks.

```
public Train getLatestTrain() {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Train.class)
    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("dateUploaded"))
    criteria.setMaxResults(1);

    return (Train) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

can provide config files if needed